# object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Tags: r, subset

I wrote some code last week wich worked perfectly.
I'm trying to use it again today. The part in trouble takes a subset of a data frame and applies `diff` and `diffinv` from column 2 to the length of the data frame/matrix. 
This is my data frame:

```
dput(d)
structure(list(Tiempo = c(1158, 1158.2, 1158.4, 1158.6, 1158.8, 
1159, 1159.2, 1159.4, 1159.6, 1159.8, 1160), UT1 = c(10500, 10500, 
10499, 10499, 10499, 10499, 10498, 10498, 10498, 10498, 10497
), UT2 = c(8238, 8238, 8238, 8238, 8238, 8238, 8238, 8238, 8238, 
8238, 8238), UT3 = c(16991, 16991, 16991, 16991, 16991, 16991, 
16990, 16990, 16990, 16989, 16989), UT4 = c(17903, 17904, 17905, 
17906, 17906, 17907, 17908, 17910, 17912, 17913, 17914), UT5 = c(16044, 
16044, 16044, 16044, 16044, 16044, 16044, 16044, 16044, 16044, 
16044), UT6 = c(16261, 16261, 16261, 16261, 16261, 16261, 16261, 
16261, 16261, 16261, 16261), UT7 = c(17094, 17094, 17094, 17094, 
17094, 17094, 17094, 17094, 17094, 17094, 17094), UT8 = c(19036, 
19037, 19036, 19037, 19037, 19037, 19038, 19038, 19039, 19040, 
19041), UT9 = c(15192, 15192, 15192, 15191, 15191, 15191, 15190, 
15190, 15189, 15189, 15188), UT10 = c(7113, 7113, 7113, 7113, 
7113, 7113, 7113, 7113, 7113, 7113, 7113), UT11 = c(3701, 3701, 
3701, 3700, 3700, 3698, 3696, 3695, 3692, 3690, 3689), UT12 = c(11666, 
11666, 11666, 11666, 11666, 11666, 11666, 11667, 11669, 11670, 
11671), TR1 = c(15805, 15805, 15805, 15805, 15805, 15805, 15805, 
15805, 15805, 15805, 15805), TR2 = c(13718, 13718, 13718, 13718, 
13718, 13718, 13718, 13718, 13718, 13718, 13718), TR3 = c(19047, 
19048, 19050, 19050, 19049, 19050, 19055, 19070, 19071, 19079, 
19087), TR4 = c(15847, 15847, 15847, 15849, 15849, 15849, 15849, 
15849, 15849, 15848, 15849), TR5 = c(21087, 21087, 21087, 21087, 
21087, 21087, 21087, 21087, 21087, 21087, 21086), TR6 = c(11434, 
11434, 11434, 11434, 11434, 11434, 11433, 11433, 11433, 11425, 
11403), TR7 = c(15769, 15769, 15769, 15769, 15769, 15769, 15769, 
15769, 15769, 15769, 15769), TR8 = c(16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 
16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915), TR9 = c(15800, 
15800, 15800, 15796, 15773, 15755, 15745, 15744, 15735, 15706, 
15697), TR10 = c(14121, 14121, 14121, 14121, 14121, 14121, 14121, 
14121, 14120, 14121, 14120), TR11 = c(18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 
18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247), TR12 = c(10877, 
10877, 10877, 10877, 10878, 10878, 10878, 10878, 10878, 10878, 
10878)), .Names = c("Tiempo", "UT1", "UT2", "UT3", "UT4", "UT5", 
"UT6", "UT7", "UT8", "UT9", "UT10", "UT11", "UT12", "TR1", "TR2", 
"TR3", "TR4", "TR5", "TR6", "TR7", "TR8", "TR9", "TR10", "TR11", 
"TR12"), row.names = 5791:5801, class = "data.frame")
```

The code worked I'm trying to run is

```
dd<-data.frame(cbind(d$Tiempo,(diffinv(abs(diff(as.matrix(c[,2:length(d)])))))))
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in c[, 2:length(d)] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

Moreover, when I use:

```
q<-c(1:25)
length(q)
[1] 25
q[4:length(q)]
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Works just as it's supposed to.
I don't have a clue about what's happening. I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you

Comment: Did you create an object named `c`?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I feel stupid. It's just I'm using a bunch of data frames named a,b,c...and so on and I constructed the code once and copy pasted it. I guess I have to pay more attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you intended to have this:

```
d[,2:length(d)]
```